# A common word for something Simple yet Powerful

Tags: adjectives, american-english

As the title says: what is a common word for something simple yet powerful?

Comment: I assume you mean 'uncomplicated', but I can't resist offering 'troll'.

Comment: Hmm, no. I'm actually serious. But as nobody has seriously answered it, I'll assume that there isn't one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want a noun? As in a *thing* which is simple but powerful, as in a grenade (or, metaphorically a pen, a sword, a crown, a word, a fist, ...)?

Comment: I was looking for an adjective. Like how a grenade is simple in design and use, but is extremely powerful.

Comment: Then I favor @OrangeWombat's *potent*; it has a sense of compactness to it; of *latent* power. A potent object is powerful, but in repose (for now).

Comment: Simple and powerful are essentially orthogonal (independent). This is like asking for a word for something that is orange yet short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the word `Potent`, as in:

> A crown is a potent symbol of authority.

A `potent symbol`, then, is one that is certainly simple, since it is immediately recognizable. `Potent` is also synonymous with `powerful`, as in:

> The image was too potent for it to be simply a dream.

Comment: No. *Potent* does **not** imply simple - **at all**. It does not follow, just because you give an example using *potent symbol*, and you claim that a potent symbol must be simple (?), that something that is *potent* is also simple.

Comment: You are correct. I posted the question hastily, which was a mistake. I decided to change the sentence quite a bit. I settled with robust.

Comment: If a symbol is potent, then is it not easily recognizable, and therefore simple? Of course "potent" does not immediately imply simple, but under certain usages it very well could.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *[brute](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brute#Adjective)*, with senses  “Crude, unpolished” and  “Strong, blunt, and spontaneous”.  For example, a brute force computing method usually is simple and obvious (or blunt, unpolished) but often is strong (manifestly capable of solving the whole range of problems it's aimed at, albeit slowly).